# Non-localizible string constants in Swift

Tags: swift

In Objective-C, I would define string constants in the `.m` file like this:

```
#define kEventID @"id"
#define kEventType @"eventType"
#define kTimestamp @"timestamp"
```

These are the strings I use, for example, as the key names in config files.

In Swift I tried doing this:

```
class Word: NSObject {
    private let kLanguageTag = "languageTag"
    private let kName = "name"
    private let kDetail = "detail"
    private let kWordID = "wordID"
    private let kWordCode = "wordCode"
```

But I am not sure if this is the right way to do it. What is the canonical way of accomplishing this task?

Comment: Actually, I think the preferred Objective-C way is NSString* const kEventID = @"id";

Comment: Regardless, the way you have it in Swift looks good, assuming you want it to be private to the Word class.

Comment: you could also try private static let kLanguageTag = "languageTag"

Comment: This looks fine, though you could also do all sorts of other fun things like nesting a struct or enum to namespace those values, and even extending system APIs so that only your special constants are allowed. See [this WWDC2015 talk for inspiration. And unicorns.](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2015-411/)